# Typescript - How do I narrow type possibilities of a generic type in a switch statement?

Tags: typescript, generic-function

I'm trying to write a function that will perform a particular calculation based on the passed key and parameters. I also want to enforce a relationship between the passed key and parameters, so I have used a generic function with a constraint:

```
interface ProductMap {
  one: {
    basePrice: number;
    discount: number;
  },
  two: {
    basePrice: number;
    addOnPrice: number;
  }
}

function getPrice<K extends keyof ProductMap>(key: K, params: ProductMap[K]) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'one': {
      return params.basePrice - params.discount; // Property 'discount' does not exist on type 'ProductMap[K]'.
    }
    case 'two': {
      return params.basePrice + params.addOnPrice;
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe I'm thinking about this in the wrong way, but it seems like typescript should be able to narrow the generic type in the switch statement. The only way I could get it to work was with this awkwardness:

```
function getPrice<K extends keyof ProductMap>(key: K, params: ProductMap[K]) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'one': {
      const p = params as ProductMap['one'];
      return p.basePrice - p.discount;
    }
    case 'two': {
      const p = params as ProductMap['two'];
      return p.basePrice + p.addOnPrice;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain why #1 won't work or offer an alternative solution?

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) for why this doesn't work.  Your type assertion solution is probably the most reasonable way of dealing with this.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCwCycADsgN4CwAUMrchiBAFznV3vIBGcAzhOsCQsQOALadoAbjYdaWYDwQYc4YWIlRpNOgF8ANDNpgA7hhaVts7nwFDkI8VMMc4WLAHkQt5vfVPLyDrUQVTUMCr4wAzIAOYQYN4APADSyBAAHpAgWDzIANYQAJ4YMGiYuPhExAB8ABQFhSzJesjEcFBwojws6Nh4hCQA2skAugCUrAFKIDxgre1gwHAANlU9C0vLib0VAzXIALzkyIMNIyxtHV2BWuzApbWXiytVAHQMEBMWsrRQ8ThQEDzKDPVYkd6MV7WfhQQQoAC0wNBbw+r3kimU4FuujSyz4yHuyEeGxe4JMGC+znYfzAAKBT02b3JUN4MLhyAA1EjGWTTK9XB4vLCkNjaDpcfiwAALTDGewQOUAUSgmCgtTGWhCQA) seem like a reasonable alternative?  It's not using an assertion, so it's "safer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"Can anyone explain why #1 won't work or offer an alternative solution?"*

Here's why #1 won't work: Typescript has [control-flow type narrowing](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/chapters/narrowing/) for variables like `key`, but not for type parameters like `K`.

The `case 'one':` check narrows the type of the variable `key: K` to `key: 'one'`.

But it does not narrow from `K extends 'one' | 'two'` to `K extends 'one'`, because no test has been done on the actual type variable `K`, nor can any test be done to narrow it. So `params: ProductMap[K]` is still `params: ProductMap[K]`, and `K` is still the same type, so the type of `params` hasn't been narrowed.

---

Here's an alternative solution: use a discriminated union, and switch on the discriminant (i.e. the `__tag` property in the code below).

```js
type ProductMap =
  {
    __tag: 'one';
    basePrice: number;
    discount: number;
  } | {
    __tag: 'two';
    basePrice: number;
    addOnPrice: number;
  }

function getPrice(params: ProductMap): number {
  switch (params.__tag) {
    case 'one': {
      return params.basePrice - params.discount;
    }
    case 'two': {
      return params.basePrice + params.addOnPrice;
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwCyBDMUC8AUFFAN7ElQD6Vw2A5gFxQDkCAdhCwNwUkBG2AM4R4ASzQRm7FAFt+EOL0pQkYoWgQp2waXIVKKAXygAfMn2q0GzFsADuCHpcEjxkvfMXLK2JEgB5dncpKBkvQxIjQkIAM20MMQ4oeghgEIAKMGw4bFkhZnhkdCxcAEpPAwsSIXsxYDQACygsnLyhADoaOnoy6so0YWg2ThZmchUSODSUOHYobNz8jtdROAloAFoFtuW1DS0dHyjLQZFWBydxyymZuZ2lztWQqABqB-aOv0Dg9cljqDRE7RIA)

Comment: The problem with this, of course, is that if you want a different return type based on each discriminant, the return type would be a union of all possible return types, rather than the one corresponding to the actual discriminant passed, like generics would do.

Comment: That's not a problem with this approach; it's a different but related question with a more complicated answer. You can still use a discriminated union and write a suitable generic signature to allow a more specific return type to be inferred at some call-sites.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, looks like TypeScript isn't so smart, but there is a workaround, which is better that casting:

```js
function getPrice(productMap: ProductMap, key: keyof ProductMap) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'one': {
      const params = productMap['one'];
      return params.basePrice - params.discount;
    }
    case 'two': {
      const params = productMap['two'];
      return params.basePrice + params.addOnPrice;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to specific type is one solution (but not the best):

```js
interface ProductMap {
  one: {
    basePrice: number;
    discount: number;
  };
  two: {
    basePrice: number;
    addOnPrice: number;
  };
}

function getPrice<K extends keyof ProductMap>(
  key: K,
  _params: ProductMap[K]
) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'one': {
      const params = _params as ProductMap['one'];
      return params.basePrice - params.discount;
    }
    case 'two': {
      const params = _params as ProductMap['two'];
      return params.basePrice + params.addOnPrice;
    }
  }
}
```

And, in order to keep a single *return type*, define the *function return type*:

```js
interface ProductMap {
  one: {
    basePrice: number;
    discount: number;
  };
  two: {
    basePrice: number;
    addOnPrice: number;
  };
}

function getPrice<K extends keyof ProductMap>(
  key: K,
  _params: ProductMap[K]
): number {
  switch (key) {
    case 'one': {
      const params = _params as ProductMap['one'];
      return params.basePrice - params.discount;
    }
    case 'two': {
      const params = _params as ProductMap['two'];
      return params.basePrice + params.addOnPrice;
    }
  }
}
```