# How to properly infer type in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, types, enums

I'm pretty new to typescript, this was probably answered before, but I can't find the answer anywhere, so here is the problem I'm trying to solve.

I have an enum

```
enum TableNames = {
  example: 'example'
  example2: 'example2',
}
```

and I have these types for my models

```
type TableName = keyof typeof TableNames

type TableState<L =any> = {
  list: Array<L>
}

type ExampleDataType = {
  id: string
  ...
}

type ExampleData2Type = {
  id: number
  ...
}

type TableStateType = {
  example: TableState<ExampleDataType>
  example2: TableState<ExampleData2Type>
}

type InterListType<TName extends TableName> = TableStateType[TName]['list'][number]
```

and I have this special function

```
const createPath = <TName extends TableNames, T = InferListType<TName>>(
  tableName: TName,
  record: T
) => {
  if (tableName === TableNames.example) {
    console.log(record) // how to get this to infer to "ExampleDataType"
  }

  if (tableName === TableNames.example2) {
    console.log(record) // how to get this to infer to "ExampleData2Type"
  }
}
```

The question is the comment above, right now I'm getting this

```
if (tableName === TableNames.example) {
  console.log(record) // T = InferListType<TName>
}
```

NOTE: typescript version is 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into this issue: [Typescript - How do I narrow type possibilities of a generic type in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075083/typescript-how-do-i-narrow-type-possibilities-of-a-generic-type-in-a-switch-st).

> Here's why [it] won't work: Typescript has control-flow type narrowing for variables like `tableName`, but not for type parameters like `T`.

JCalz mentions a workaround in the comments that might help. Looks something like this:

```
type ExampleDataType = {
  id: string
  data1: string
}

type ExampleDataType2 = {
  id: string
  data2: string
}

type TableToRecordMap = {
  example: ExampleDataType
  example2: ExampleDataType2
}

type TableName = keyof TableToRecordMap

type TableState<L =any> = {
  list: Array<L>
}

type TableStateType = {
  [Table in TableName]: TableState<TableToRecordMap[Table]>
}

const createPath = <TName extends TableName>(
  tableName: TName,
  record: TableToRecordMap[TName]
) => {
  const partialTable: Partial<TableToRecordMap> = { [tableName]: record };

  if (partialTable.example) {
    console.log(partialTable.example)
  } else if (partialTable.example2) {
    console.log(partialTable.example2)
  }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCIOAgKuaAXigG8AoKKASwBMAuKAZ2ACcqA7AcwqhuwQCMDZmy5kAvmTKhIsRCnRYc%20SACYoxcpVrDWHbpT45Vu0d0nSCUXAgBG6XAHsAShADGjljQCyCMBtIeCHk0CAZ4ZFClPAIgkPQTOUjFfhUIVQkpGWgbewgAOWQiKABrCBBHADNrOwcXd08fPyyrXPQAZRxgCAAeABkNBHYQAD4ArShUKmYGAEEWFgQQfpHMy1k2iE7sCDTxngBtTep2GrzCpAgAXQZN7e6ezadXDy9fMCPa69WLD3ZmKBuFgQHYABWwAAsAo8LtBgt12DRGGd0LCRgAKHg4c5FW6wgA0PGBr3oKN29RJ7yOsKuZAAlBoxhM-gCwAgWMAqAhUJsGOCOVzUI8vs8Gm8-GNNFADtjUUUblBiY0oOIANxSbTVdFsgXczYAOmCyQgDImlBZjnQ%20tQjk42vZnL1X0N8RNPHEUAgqEY0CoWp1jp5zqNCnSpp45sc-0tEGttvtuqDeRdxtUdPdElVQA)

Comment: hey thanks for answering, I tried it with the first approach, but it's still giving me this result

```
if (tableName === TableNames.example) {
    console.log(tableName) // TName extends TableNames
    console.log(record) // InferListType<TName>
  }
```

Comment: Ya you're right! With the addition of an extra table it breaks for me. I'll update the answer to accommodate.